# How to prevent passing notifications from Android device to watches?

Tags: android, notifications

I have an app that sends some notifications (`android.app.Notification`) via `NotificationManagerCompat`.

Notifications can be wery frequent. So, when watches (for example, Garmin) are connected to Android device, sometimes everything you see are notifications.

Is there a way to send notifications only to device itself, without passing them to connected watches?

Answer (score 0):

This is called *bridging*. You can disable bridging for your app by adding this to your app manifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.wearable.notificationBridgeMode"
    android:value="NO_BRIDGING" />
```

See [the Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/bridger#disable-bridging) for more details and other use cases